# Merge multiple HTML files in reverse order?

Tags: cat, html, merge

I have [multiple HTML files for this book](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~bengioy/dlbook/). I am trying to add them in opposite order.

I've tried:

```
 cat *.html >> merge.html
```

I've tried to use tac on the list of downloaded files by time to no avail:

```
tac $(ls -t) >> output_file.html
```

When I open up the file, it continually seems to flash and pages are missing.

lcd047 recommended below that I use htmldoc. When following [the installation](https://www.msweet.org/documentation/project1/HTMLDOC.html#INSTALL), I run into the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `ENTER'.  Stop.
```

When I try to run it in command line on the document download from [here](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~bengioy/dlbook/intro.html), I run into this issue:

```
ERR011: Unable to parse HTML element on line 2011 of intro.html!
PAGES: 1 
BYTES: 39062
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to combine multiple pages into one long HTML document?

Comment: I'm trying to combine multiple HTML files (chapters) into a single long HTML document (book)

Comment: It won't work. HTML language defines a structure called DOM (Document Object Model) **for a single page**. *Merging HTML files to make a big one is like trying to build a limousine crashing one car into other*.

Comment: If `ls -t` gives the direct order, you could try `cat $( ls -t | tac ) >>output.html`.  But beware that `cat` doesn't deal with HTML headers and the like.  A better solution might be to use something like [HTMLDOC](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1) or [Sigil](http://sigil-ebook.com/).

Comment: @lcd047 when I try to run "make install ENTER" as part of the htmldoc tutorial, I run into this error...make: *** No rule to make target `ENTER'.  Stop

Comment: @jcbermu how would you recommend I get around this then?

Answer (score 2):

When you "cat" files together, you're going to end up with extra markup you don't need.  Notably, you'll have `<html>` and `</html>` tags, which will screw up your rendering.  You'll also have multiple `<head>` sections.  Those pages don't look like they use Javascript, but I didn't check closely - colliding Javascript namespaces can also screw you up with this approach.

For such a small set of HTML pages, you're probably best off doing this by hand, or creating a merged HTML (CHM) file.  However, there are other ways to accomplish this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866929/merge-two-html-files-into-master-html-file

Comment: The first link has pointers to some very interesting tools, thank you.